# Relative MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a MySQL database table which is built as follows.
[image: User database]
The numbers below the classes denote a "level" for the class, such as high, medium, or low, with 0 being does not attend that class.

I need to build another table to save homework assignments for each class, but I'm a bit lost as to how I'd build that table, specifically denoting what the exact columns of the rows have to be, since each class does not have something specific that denotes it.

Comment: You need to normalize the structure into `users`, `classes`, and `homework`. Then you can have a `users_classes` relationship table and a `users_homework` table as well.

Comment: users, classes, and homework being tables?

Comment: If you really don't want to normalize the structure, you could always have a `users_homework` table with columns `hw_id`, `username`, and `subject`. That's gross though.

Answer (score 1):

A properly normalized structure would have a separate table for courses, giving each an id, and another table placing students into courses by including a student id, course id, and level.

```
CREATE TABLE students (
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  username VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  password VARCHAR(64), 
  email VARCHAR(...)
  UNIQUE KEY (username)
);

CREATE TABLE courses (
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL
);

/* If a record doesn't exist for a course and student, 
   the student isn't enrolled in that course. Otherwise,
   the level is defined here */
CREATE TABLE enrollments (
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  student_id INT NOT NULL,
  course_id INT NOT NULL,
  level INT NOT NULL,
  /* Each student may be enrolled only once per course */
  UNIQUE KEY (student_id, course_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES students (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (course_id) REFERENCES courses (id)
);
```

Finally then, you can create a table for assignments assigned in each course:

```
CREATE TABLE assignments (
  id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  course_id INT NOT NULL,
  description TEXT
  /*... other columns related to the assignment as necessary*/
);
```

And for students to complete assignments if necessary:

```
CREATE TABLE student_assignments (
  student_id INT NOT NULL,
  assignment_id INT NOT NULL,
  assignment_body TEXT, /* or whatever... */
  /* Or to track when completed */
  submitted_timestamp TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (student_id, assignment_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (assignment_id) REFERENCES assignments (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES students (id)
);
```

Comment: What exactly does the table "for students to complete assignments" do? I can't exactly see how it defines if something is completed.

Comment: @AlexCastro Put whatever you need in there. Basically the skeleton I have there has only a TEXT column for the contents of a student's assignment (as though the submitted assignment is stored in the database). If what you want to track is if/when an assignment is submitted, just use a `submitted_time` timestamp column.  When a student turns in an assignment, the row is added and timestamp set. If a student has no row, no assignment was completed.

Comment: Thanks! I was also wondering how exactly the levels were defined? The database here seems to just store a number for the levels.

Comment: @AlexCastro I just made it a number like you had in your example, I didn't add a relational table to define the numbers. You could do that, or just store "high,middle,low" in a varchar column instead of that number.